# Plugin system that keeps alive objects

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, .net-assembly, appdomain

I have an application that needs to load and unload at runtime some plugins in the form of .dll files. Those dll files contain one or more classes that derive from my abstract class Module which looks like this:

```
public abstract class Module : MarshalByRefObject
{
    //various fields here, not reported as they are not useful to understand

   public abstract void Print();

}
```

From what I understood: the only way in C# to unload an assembly and its classes is to put the assembly in a dedicated Appdomain and then unload it when it's not needed anymore and the only way to communicate between AppDomains is to derive from MarshalByRefObject or MarshalByValueObject. Then When I pass a reference of the Module to another AppDomain I don't really get the object but a transparent proxy. Can anyone confirm what i wrote above please?

Ok now the real problem: let's say in my file PersonPlugin.dll I have a "Person" class that extends Module. this class contains the fields name, lastname and phone number.

The method Print, which is called periodically (it doesn't make sense to call print periodically, but it's an example) prints those 3 fields.

Later I build a new dll with a new version of the class Person, that has a new field called address and Print method now prints also the address. 
NB: Plugins are made by 3rd parties and I can't know if the new version is similar to the older or completely different, but in my case it's safe to assume that a class Person wouldn't differ that much between versions.

I then replace the old dll file with this new file (the dll is shadowcopied in a dedicated appdomain so the file is writable / deletable)

A FileSystemWatcher notices the change and:

1. creates a new appdomain for the new dll
2. saves the state of the old instantiated Person objects
3. assignes the Person objects from the old Person class to the new one
4. unloads the appdomain containing the old Person class
5. the application starts printing the new string containing also the address (that is null at least in the beginning)

Points 2 and 3 are the core of my problem: How can I keep alive those objects (or at least their fields) after unloading their class and then instantiate a new class which has the same name and similar properties, but that is in fact another class?

This is what i though so far:

1. using reflection I can copy in a dictionary every field of every Person object, delete the old objects and then instantiate new ones and copy back the fields where possible (if an old field is not present it's skipped an if a new one is present it gets its default value)
2. using something like MessagePack to automatically serialize the old Person objects and then deserialize them to new Person objects

However I didn't made any test to see if those 2 solutions may work, mainly because I'd like to know before starting to write code if those 2 solutions may work in reality or just in my mind and because maybe some of you have a more polished / working solution or even better a framework / library which already does that.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I realized that asking this question without contextualizing it a bit may lead to some misunderstanding, so:
The question I'm asking is about my thesis, which is a modular minimal game engine (not a server). The idea is to make the engine modular and, to make it simple to test various features, its modules can be changed at runtime applying immediately the changes without restarting or loosing the state of the "actors" in the game. 
A dll contains 1 to many modules. every dll is loaded in 1 AppDomain, so if I unload that appdomain, I unload every module in it. Modules inside the same appdomain can have direct references to eachothers, since when unloaded they are unloaded all together. Modules in different assemblies (so also different AppDomains) communicates using a message bus and never have direct references. If a module consuming the message is unloaded, the system will simply stop forwarding that message to that module.

What is important is that what a module represents is up to the user of the engine: a module may represent a single game object like a car, or a whole physics module. I won't dig into further details as they are useless right now, but what I want to achieve may be exemplified by this:

I have a dll containing a module called Car which always moves forward. I change the dll with a new one containing the module Car that now moves always backward.
The result is that once I replace the dll, the car will immediately invert its direction.

Of course this example is stupid, there are methods to achieve this in a far more easy way. However this can also apply in a situation where I find a bug in my code, I correct it, submit it and the bug simply disappears, or even more complicated situations.

That's why I need to keep alive objects (I mean, keep their state alive) and the whole system too.

And about your point 2: there are no hard limits about why I would not allow to coexist 2 modules of the same type but different versions as long as they are in different namespaces or in different dlls since in my system every module is identified and referenced with a different ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me comment on your first point.

> From what I understood: the only way in C# to unload an assembly and
>   its classes is to put the assembly in a dedicated Appdomain and then
>   unload it when it's not needed anymore and the only way to communicate
>   between AppDomains is to derive from MarshalByRefObject or
>   MarshalByValueObject. Then When I pass a reference of the Module to
>   another AppDomain I don't really get the object but a transparent
>   proxy. Can anyone confirm what i wrote above please?

**Confirmed.**

This is entirely accurate. .NET assemblies cannot be unloaded from an `AppDomain` after they have been loaded. The entire `AppDomain` must be unloaded.

In the case of a modular system you must load the plugins in a separate `AppDomain` and marshal data between the host app and the plugin.

Now, to address to your question about loading modules on the fly and persisting their state. You can absolutely do this but you need to establish a contract between your module and your host application.

There is no need to mark your module as `MarshalByRefObject` since that will introduce additional restrictions on the module implementation and also brings additional overhead. Instead, I would have my module contract be as light as possible by using an interface to represent the contract.

```
public interface IModule
{
    Person GetPerson();
    void Print();
}
```

Any data that needs to be passed between the host application and module needs to inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` so your Person class should look something like this if you intend to pass it back and forth.

```
public class Person : MarshalByRefObject
{
    ...
}
```

Now, regarding persisting the state of `Person` even though new attributes have been added.

Since your host application doesn't need to know about these new attributes, you should move the persistent of these types of objects into a `ModuleManager` which lives inside the `AppDomain` for the plugin and expose some methods on your `IModule` that know how to do the actual persistence.

```
public interface IModule
{
    Person GetPerson();
    void Print();

    IDictionary<string, object> GetState();
    void SetState(IDictionary<string, object> state);
}

public class ModuleManager : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public IModule Module { get; set; }

    public void Initialize(string path)
    {
        // Load the module
        // Setup file watcher
    }

    public void SaveState(string file)
    {
        var state = this.Module.GetState();
        // Write this state to a file
    }

    public void LoadState(string file)
    {
        var state = this.ReadState(file);
        this.Module.SetState(state);
    }

    private IDictionary<string, object> ReadState(string file)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `ModuleManager` should be responsible for saving the state of the module so each module developer doesn't have to implement this functionality. All it has to do is read and write it's state to and from a dictionary of key/value pairs.

You will find this approach manageable rather than trying to perform all the persistence in your host application.

The idea here is marshal as little data as possible between the host app and plugin. Each plugin knows what fields are available in `Person` so let them be responsible for indicating what needs to be persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the AppDomain Randy. So you reccomend that every module is responsable for its own state load/save instead of the host application? I guess it can work,but now the responsability of the state persistency is up to the module developer (which may not even be that bad actually). I made the module inherit from MarshalByRefObject because I need some of its methods (like Print) to be called by the host, so the module must be bassed across its boundary.I guess I could also pass a "container" object with the only purpose to share data between a module and its host.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I would leverage a container that is responsible for managing the plugin within the spawned AppDomain. Also, you don't have to leave the persistence entirely up to the module developer. You could introduce a method which returns key/value pairs to represent the state of the module and the container (ModuleManager in my example) could be responsible for doing the actual persistence so this way everything is consistent across all modules.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide an example of what the state persistence inside the ModuleManager might look like.

Comment: Looking at your example I may have had an idea: I represent Module as an abstract class, and I set "SetState" and "GetState" as virtual methods and implement them to load / save the object's state in a "standard" way. This way If the module developer doesn't want to mess with state persistency he doesn't to anything, otherwise if he needs a more sophisticated persistency or if he doesn't even want persistency he can override those 2 methods in its own module.

Comment: Yeah, that would work as well. My goal was to provide you with some guidance as to how these things might be done. It is by all means not the only way to do things. I hope my answer has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you really want to play around with a hornet's nest.

There are a few design considerations that you don't mention

1) Why do you need to be 'online' all the time. Why can't you be offline for say a 1 hour reboot once a week. Whatever solution you implement (reflection/serializaiton) will give you a performance cost, not to mention a huge overhead in maintenance.

2) Could it ever be possible that you want 2 versions of the same plugin. In the java world there is a framework called OSGI. and what you do there is that you take a dependency on a certain module, but that in some cases it is possible to have 2 versions of the same module be online at the same time. Especially when a person class added an address field then all persons need to be upgraded some how deal with this. Also all the modules depending on the person module would need to be upgraded at the same time at well.

I'm not saying there is never a reason not to have what you want. but i think you should really reconsider your approach to see if you are meeting the requirements in the right way.

That said i think you should look at a microservices architecture. Then each module would for example be it's own webapi. Each module is responsible for keeping itself alive (you could have some small wrappers around all modules to avoid code duplication here). Then you could just call a module using webapi and your standard newtonsoft json serialization would take care of the rest (and/or message bus, similar idea there, slightly different implementation). 
The advantage being is that if you call /api/print then the module would print the person. If you ever have a new module that for some reason can't implement print but implements /api/writeline then the module would be responsible to implement the logic too convert calls from the old /api/print to the new /api/writeline.

And a message bus implementation might suit your needs even better. You just queue the commands you want to have handled and if after an upgrade your modules is back online it starts processing all messages from the messagebus.

Comment: Hi Batavia, thanks for the answer. I updated my original question to better contextualizing it and explain better my situation